# E-Mail with csv attachment processed in Salesforce

Tags: email, csv, import, data-import, emailfileattachment

It is possible to send an email with an attachment to salesforce and that this attachment will be processed there? The attachment contain multiple columns and rows for update or create records.

Comment: You cannot do this without code, but you can do it in Apex quite easily.

Comment: ok, but can you give me some tipps or ideas how can I do that? I searched a bit with google, but I can't find information.

Answer (score 1):

You will need two things:

- [Apex Email Service and InboundEmailHandler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_what_is.htm?search_text=apex%20email)
- A CSV parser. My favorite is [this one by Marty Chang](https://github.com/martyychang/sfdc-csv)

If the attachment is "large" in byte terms, you may run into Heap issues