# How to automate permission set assignment checking?

Tags: unit-test, permission-sets, test-automation

I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets with the names of different countries and in each of these sheets there are permissions sets for each profiles, there are 6 such profiles. Like Canada Sheet -> Rep Profile: n number of permission sets, Manager Profile: m number of permission sets and so on.

I have to verify if all the permission sets in the sheet are assigned to the user for the specific profile and country.

Is there a way to automate this testing process? I've been doing this manually using VLOOKUP and it takes a long time and its a tedious process.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Have you checked the [User Access and Permission Assistant app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FeF99UAF)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a "custom coding" way to perform the necessary operations that you would prefer, i.e., [Email Services](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_email_services.htm&type=5). Here, you have to write custom logic to process the contents, headers, and attachments of inbound email to Salesforce provided email address. If you are not familiar with the steps involved, I would highly recommend to check this: [What are Email Services](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_email_services_overview.htm&type=5).

You also need to implement CSV parser to 'read' the data on the sheet and perform whatever operation (verifications) you are required. Refer this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/349532/44898) to get an idea on the parsing technique.

But, if you are just looking to 'verify' permission sets on a few specific users, 'VLOOKUP' would be your best friend. It is still a great way to check quickly and accurately, even it is a bit tedious job to perform.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do comparison of permissions across profiles in Excel, there exists an open source Node JS plugin called compare-permissions that does this very well.

https://masaaki-taguchi.github.io/compare-permissions/

https://github.com/masaaki-taguchi/compare-permissions

> Compare permissions is a CLI tool that exports Salesforce's profile and permission set settings to Excel.
> It also supports multiple organizations and makes it possible to compare their settings on Excel.

*Disclosure: I do not have any affiliation with this tool*

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for Permission Set Groups. It may be some work up front, but maintenance would be a snap.

1. Create a Permission Set Group for each Profile/Country combo (ie "Rep - Canada" or similar)
2. Add the appropriate permission sets into each group based on your spreadsheet
3. Remove Permission Sets from users and add the appropriate groups
4. Your sheet is no longer needed - the documentation is in the Permission Set Group - unless you want to maintain it in two places